# PHP Create and Save a txt file to root directory

Tags: php

I am trying to create and save a file to the root directory of my site, but I don't know where its creating the file as I cannot see any. And, I need the file to be overwritten every time, if possible.

Here is my code:

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

How can I set it to save on the root?

Comment: That looks right to me.  As long as the script is located in your web root then it should be ok.  The only thing that would stop it is your permissions.

Comment: If you have permission try `$fp = fopen("/myText.txt","wb");`

Comment: Other than being a bad idea, and seemingly hackery, just make sure to specify full path, and have enough permissions.

Comment: Setting 777 on your web root is a horribly bad idea.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It's creating the file in the same directory as your script.  Try this instead.

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Just a note: This needs write permission to the directory you are writing to.

Comment: I can't write content to that file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 19):

If you are running PHP on Apache then you can use the enviroment variable called `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. This means that the path is dynamic, and can be moved between servers without messing about with the code.

```
<?php
  $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
  $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
  $content = "Your text here";
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked years ago but here is a modern approach using PHP5 or newer versions.

```
  $filename = 'myfile.txt'
  if(!file_put_contents($filename, 'Some text here')){
   // overwriting the file failed (permission problem maybe), debug or log here
  }
```

If the file doesn't exist in that directory it will be created, otherwise it will be overwritten unless FILE_APPEND flag is set.
`file_put_contents` is a built in function that has been available since PHP5.

[Documentation for file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` will open a resource in the same directory as the file executing the command.  In other words, if you're just running the file ~/test.php, your script will create ~/myText.txt.

This can get a little confusing if you're using any URL rewriting (such as in an MVC framework) as it will likely create the new file in whatever the directory contains the root index.php file.

Also, you must have correct permissions set and may want to test before writing to the file.  The following would help you debug:

```
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","wb");
if( $fp == false ){
    //do debugging or logging here
}else{
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
```