# How to save Username and Password in a Text File?

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords

I know this Question is a Duplicate but all the Questions in StackOverFlow and other Websites are not helping me... So i want to save the Username and Password from the Input in a `.txt` file but everything i have tried have not worked so far. This is PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit-Button']))
    {
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
    $fp = fopen('accounts.txt', 'a+');

    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'Saved';
    }
fclose ($fp);
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
die();
}?>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<span>Username</span>
<input type="text" name="Username" id="Login-Input-Username">

<span>Password</span>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Login-Input-Password">

<button type="submit" name="Submit-Button" value="submit" id="Login-
Button">Sign In</button>
```

So the `accounts.txt` File is empty after i click Sign In and i can't understand why it is not working.

Comment: I think you should check accounts.txt file path or permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP create text file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686644/php-create-text-file-on-server)

Comment: @RP The accounts.txt File is in the same path with index.php. And what do you mean with permission?

Comment: your file must have a write mode like set permissions to 777. you can search about it in google than how can set the permission in linux or window etc.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to store passwords in a TXT file? the way you are storing the password is so insecure, except if you are making a phishing page.... are you?

Comment: @MehdiBounya I am in a learning curve trying to learn hacking so yes you are right this is for a Phishing Website but it's just a test i am not going to use it :)

Comment: @MehdiBounya The Website is all coded by me its not the Source Code of another Website so... Even if i was asking a question about Phishing is there anything to stop me because it still a programming question. I mean it allowed, right?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the source of your page and I think you forgot to add "action" and "method" to your form.

```
 <form action="action.php" method="post">
```

[image]