# PHP Create and Save a txt file to my folder directory

Tags: php

I am trying to create and save a file to the root directory of my site but file going to root directory .I want to save my file to my folder which name is allfiles

Here is the code:

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

How can I set it to save on the allfiles folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Create and Save a txt file to root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$fileName = "example.txt";
$contents = "put your file content here";
$fileNameWithPath = "your_path".$fileName;
if(file_put_contents($fileNameWithPath, $contents)){
  echo "File ". basename($fileNameWithPath) ." was successfully created.";
}
else{
  echo "Failed to create file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add /allfiles folder before the file

```
$content = "some text here";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/allfiles/myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```