# How to create file in special directory using PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

How can I create a file on the server in the directory I want using php? I found the function `fopen` but it won't help me, because we cannot choose the directory.

Example:

```
$href = '/contact/downloads/227856/file2.php'    
if (file_exists($href)) {
    echo "File exists";
} else {
    echo "File doesn't exist, but we will create it";

// And there we gonna create the file in the directory $href
}
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: visite this link this will help
[visited this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path_to_file = " " //Make sure $path_to_file is the full path, something like /home/user/public_html/etc/ <br>  
$yourFileName = 'myfile';
$ourFileHandle= fopen($path_to_file.$yourFileName, 'w') or die('Permission error');
```

Comment: Warning: fopen(/ ....  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ .....     can't create file

Comment: change it to 
 
`$path_to_file = " " //Make sure $path_to_file is the full path, something like /home/user/public_html/etc/ <br>
$ourFileHandle= fopen($path_to_file.$yourFileName, 'w') or die('Permission error');`

Comment: Actually i found the error it's because the directory doesn't fully exists "/227856/file2.php"  how to create file and directory at the same time i mean the "227856" folder

Comment: you have to add 
 `mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);` 
if you want to create the folder if it doesn't already exist you have to de these 
`if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}`

Comment: so I must select the directory from $href with substr, but what if directory changes ? (for example 7 numbers not 6 ) ? how can I automate the process

Comment: then use explode
`$s = explode("/",$href);
$directory_name=count($s)-2;
print $s[$directory_name];`