# PHP - Cant save string variable to text file, gets corrupted

Tags: php

New to PHP and im reading a textfile into a string variable, removing double quotes and writing the contents back to a textfile. The problem is that the textfile, after saving, just consists of junk like this:

> ^@2^@0^@1^@0^@-^@1^@1^@-^@2^@0^@
>   ^@1^@3^@:^@5^@5^@,^@^@H^@K^@L^@M^@\^@S^@o^@f...

I am obviously doing something very wrong here..
Here is the code:

```
function replacequotes("myCommaSeparatedFile.csv")
{
    $rfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $outputfile = fopen("test2.csv", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $readtext = fread($rfile, filesize($filename));
    $textoutput = str_replace('"', '', $readtext);

    echo $textoutput; // <- this shows ok on screen

    fwrite($outputfile, $textoutput);
    fclose($inpufile);
    fclose($outputfile);
}
```

Can someone help me out please, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Create and Save a txt file to root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory)

Comment: The "junk" you posted is not junk at all. It is text encoded as UTF-16BE. Open it in Notepad and it renders correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. `dos2unix` was a useful command. Thanks again Ali for the code cleaning!